# Stopping JavaScript manipulation to YouTube embed code

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

I am trying to add a YouTube embed link on to a web page I did not originally develop (and therefore not that familiar with it) with lots of different things already going on with it (i.e. many other js calls, etc) - so in other words for a novice JavaScript debugger like me it is pretty tricky to identify things.

For some reason, the page changes any YouTube embed link to a near full screen width video. I want it to simply run as per the code I am pasting in, which for this example is:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/tGvHNNOLnCk?rel=0" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I can see the code it swaps it out with is:

```
<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/tGvHNNOLnCk?rel=0" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" id="fitvid802730"></iframe></div>
```

When I turn JavaScript off, the embedded video displays at the right size, and uses the original code - so it's clear to me it has something to do with JavaScript.

Bearing in mind I am new to JavaScript debugging, What is the easiest way to somehow cleanly disrupt any operations on this kind of code so there are no manipulations done to the youtube embed code?

I am using Google Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Search through the JavaScript code for "fluid-width-video" for starters. Without seeing the code it's really hard to suggest anything specific.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. I will look. It's the kind of website that on some pages this effect (fluid-width-video) might want to be used, is it possible simply to add some code on this page in question that 'blocks' out 'fluid-width-video' ?

Comment: Well yes, that's certainly possible, but again without any visibility into the nature of the code involved it's impossible to be specific.